# Can't discover the source of virus. Faulty dll is causing many windows pop up

Tags: virus-removal, malware-removal, malware-detection

Attached here some samples of faulty bug report windows which pop up occasionally.

```
Nvidia Container:
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   BEX64
  Application Name: nvcontainer.exe
  Application Version:  1.19.2734.4859
  Application Timestamp:    5d8a4cce
  Fault Module Name:    LvHook64.dll_unloaded
  Fault Module Version: 0.0.0.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   4ef99ce6
  Exception Offset: 0000000180083b64
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Data:   0000000000000008
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.4
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 01bd
  Additional Information 2: 01bdf4bdebcec42eebba611d82627136
  Additional Information 3: e2ab
  Additional Information 4: e2abf6ef2e97b2d3022984fc32807e20

Google Installer:
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   BEX
  Application Name: GoogleUpdate.exe
  Application Version:  1.3.33.7
  Application Timestamp:    5968275f
  Fault Module Name:    LvHook.dll_unloaded
  Fault Module Version: 0.0.0.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   4ef99d42
  Exception Offset: 3aa6461a
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Data:   00000008
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.4
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Adobe Flash:
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: FlashUtil32_32_0_0_303_pepper.exe
  Application Version:  32.0.0.303
  Application Timestamp:    5dd86963
  Fault Module Name:    ntdll.dll
  Fault Module Version: 6.1.7601.18247
  Fault Module Timestamp:   521ea8e7
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 000343e0
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.4
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

[sample of window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXpA1.png)

Comment: Do you use [ABBYY Lingvo](https://www.file.net/process/lvhook.dll.html) at all?

Comment: I do, I check program behavior. Abbey Lingvo utilizing that dll for every program. I don't know internals, it's related to OCR function I think

Comment: Either update or uninstall that program, it appears to be faulty. If the problems go away then the problem is not a virus.

Comment: All of those are associated with Chrome.

Comment: @Mokubai I tried, doesn't help.

Comment: @AlexZubkov What exactly did you try? I gave two options, if updating doesn't work then completely uninstalling should.

Comment: I would get a dump file of the process when it crashes.  Create the directory C:\dumps\. Download procdump (MS/Sysinternals) to that directory.  In an admin prompt from the above directory run: `procdump -ma -i C:\dumps`.  Next time a process crashes you will have a dump file or 2, only the first one is required for a given process.  Maybe you can share the dump to be analyzed.

Comment: @Mokubai i got up to date version, app removal isn't an option due to nessesarity.

Comment: @AlexZubkov Then the next option would be contacting the software developers. their software has flaws and they need to fix it.

Comment: @HelpingHand https://pastebin.com/XXwhVQsH